# Java Generics not accepting class that extends parent with correct type

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to create a few structure classes so I can easily build a structure but the generics don't accept the class even though it seems to have the right type.

I have a basic `Structure` class that just stores a parent of the generic type `T`:

```
public abstract class Structure<T>{...}
```

Then I have a `KeyedStructure` that stores both a key of type `K` and extends `Structure` with type `V`:

```
public abstract class KeyedStructure <K, V> extends  Structure<V>{...}
```

Finally, I have a `KeyedBidirectionalStructure` class that has types `<K, PARENT, CHILD>` but the `CHILD` has to be able to store this class as its parent so it extends `KeyedStructure<K, KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT, CHILD>>`:

```
public abstract class KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT, CHILD extends KeyedStructure<K, KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT, CHILD>>> extends KeyedStructure<K, PARENT>{...}
```

But when I try to implement it like this:

```
class Group extends KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Group>{...}
```

or even like this

```
class Task extends KeyedStructure<String, Group>{...}
class Group extends KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Task>
```

Java keeps complaining that the `CHILD` type does extend the right class but it seems to fit the generics. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I can't make sense of what you're trying to actually do, but it feels like you're headed in the wrong direction. This class definition is really something.. `abstract class KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT, CHILD extends KeyedStructure<K, KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT, CHILD>>>
extends KeyedStructure<K, PARENT> { }`

Comment: Perhaps a simple implementation of the three classes would make things clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declaration of `Group` extends `KeyedBidirectionalStructure` with the third type argument (for `CHILD`) being `Group`. So this `Group` needs to satisfy the bound of `CHILD`, which, with everything substituted in, is `extends KeyedStructure<String, KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Group>>`. But it doesn't satisfy this. `Group` extends `KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Group>` which in turn extends `KeyedStructure<String, Group>`. Do you see the difference? In one case, the second type argument is `Group`, and in the other, the second type argument is `KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Group>`. They don't match.

Generic type arguments are invariant. `List<String>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>` even though `String` is a subtype of `Object`. So similarly `KeyedStructure<String, Group>` is not a subtype of `KeyedStructure<String, KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Group>>`, even though `Group` is a subtype of `KeyedBidirectionalStructure<String, Group, Group>`.

If you want polymorphism in the type arguments, you need to use a wildcard. So if you changed the bound to something like this, your declaration of `Group` should work:

```
public abstract class KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT,
    CHILD extends KeyedStructure<K, ? extends KeyedBidirectionalStructure<K, PARENT, CHILD>>>
    extends KeyedStructure<K, PARENT> {...}
```

However, there are other consequences of using a wildcard, and I am not sure if it makes sense without understanding your full design.